# large set sql query

Tags: mysql, ruby

I am using ruby to perform a query on a MySQL db.  I'm looking for matches of uids with:

```
WHERE uid in #{VERY_LARGE_COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST}
```

The VERY_LARGE_COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST is over 30k entries

```
VERY_LARGE_COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST = ' "one","two","three",...,"30k" '
```

and it causes sql to dump error:

```
Mysql2::Error - MySQL server has gone away:
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Can someone edit this? What's the question here? Where is your 'large' string of data come from? is it a text file, csv file, or just a string?

Comment: There is not one question mark in your *question* David... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gone-away.html

Comment: thanks. edited it.  I was wondering what the best approach is to break up the large query into smaller chunks.  thanks again.

Comment: Is `VERY_LARGE_COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST` all numbers or text as well?

Comment: they are all hex numbers in string format

Comment: You might get a performance boost if they were interpreted as numbers ie `IN (45632,894578945,8849)` vs `("45632","894578945","8849")` then the sql optimizer can do integer comparison instead of string comparison. But I'm not sure about breaking it up unless you do a `UNION` as suggested below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be going over typical 1MB mysql SQL command buffer.

To solve your problem, you should create (possibly temporary) table `uids` which contains just uid's, something like

```
CREATE TABLE uids (uid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```

(be sure that index exists for `uid`).

Then INSERT necessary uid's into `uids` table in few statements like this:

```
INSERT INTO uids (uid) VALUES (1),(5),(10),..;
```

Finally, run your query as:

```
 WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM uids)
```

or join like this:

```
 SELECT m.*
 FROM master m, uids u
 WHERE m.uid = u.uid
 ...
```

In the end, you may want to drop your `uids` table.

**EDIT**: I missed that your `uid` is not integer. Simply adjust definitions for it to use `VARCHAR` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like your query is timing out or running out of memory - do you see any errors in MySQL logs that suggest this?

I have a feeling that you are overloading your server.

And you should have :

`where uid in ( #{VERY_LARGE_CSV} )`

EDIT:
You could split the CSV then run something like:

```
SELECT * from TBL where uid in ( #{CSV_SUBSET} )t1
UNION
SELECT * from TBL where uid in ( #{CSV_REMAINDER} )t2
```

And so on.

Comment: thanks. yes. i'm wondering is there a recommended way to break up a large query into smaller chunks and then recombine.

Comment: This is NOT going to help because total buffer size will remain about the same

Comment: agreed - I never said it would be better, but the concept is the same, split it up programmatically and you will save some overhead, per run - but really the query needs to be optimized if it is failing, it will probably fail split up as well.